# Does Fluent Migrator work with .net core app?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, fluent-migrator

I am trying to use Fluent Migrator with `.net core2` application with no success (i did had a success with using Fluent Migrator with .net framework application).

What i did is the follow:

1. Created a new Class library project in the solution.
2. Added Flunt-migrator, ver 3.1.3
3. Created classes that inherit from `Migration` class.
4. implement the Down() and Up() functions.
   located the `Migrate.exe` file under windows `Users` folder
5. in the migration project properties window, updated the `build output path` to the path of the `Migrate.exe` file.

ran `build` on the project, but the tables wasn't created under the 
data base tables.

did i missed something?

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://parsstudent.com/fluentmigrator-aspnet-core-2/) would suggest that yes it does work, I don't have a huge amount of experience with fluent migrator but if i had to guess I would suspect the issue is that you are referencing a .exe rather than import the nuget packages

Comment: i did everything mentioned in that post that you mentioned, but how do i run the migration? `msbuild` process? it's not mention there..

Comment: Do you still need help on that? I can help. I have tested it with Cli tool and In-process runner. https://fluentmigrator.github.io/articles/quickstart.html?tabs=runner-in-process

Answer (score 1):

Fluentmigrator do support .NET core. All you just need to do is to follow their quick start guidelines. [Documentation Quick Start](https://fluentmigrator.github.io/articles/quickstart.html?tabs=runner-in-process)